# Replacing an element on page using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, flowplayer

I have a video player that runs client-side, and I want to store a configuration for it so I don't have to write it each single time.

I had an idea where I could place a marker in the markup, such as:

```
<player id="Player1" #marker></player>
```

Or something to that effect, and then replace `#marker` with the settings I have stored in the javascript function.

I know some basic Javascript, but I have never done something so advanced.

Here is an example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    flowplayer("player", "http://www.easymuaythai.com/Videos/FlowPlayer/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf", #marker);
</script>
```

Where it says #marker, I want to replace it with:

```
{
        clip: {
            Scaling: 'fit',
            onStart: function (clip) {
                var w = parseInt(clip.metaData.width, 10),
                    h = parseInt(clip.metaData.height, 10);
                $(this.getParent()).css({
                    width: w,
                    height: h
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post more code - how you create/initialize the player for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JQuery,
add this to the Head section of your page :

`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

then write this in your js file or section

`$('#player1').attr('playerConfiguration', 'Value');`

that will cause `<player id="Player1" playerConfiguration="value"></player>` 
hope that helps...

Comment: Do I have to place the markup before the element has loaded or after? And if the element is not found, it does nothing right?

Comment: Well if the element is not found at most cases it will not work and thats it, but if the user has turned js debugging on...well it will probebly throw an error u can write something that check that. you can use the Jquery(Document).ready(function() { if ($("#player1")){
  // add attribute to the element.
}; });

Comment: Sorry...
Jquery(Document).ready(function() { if ($("#player1").length > 0){
  // add attribute to the element.
}; });

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help you ? It creates and sets an attribute (marker) to the player node and it gives it a value (config)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var p = {
                onload: function() {
                    var markerAttribute = document.createAttribute("marker");
                    document.getElementById("Player1").setAttributeNode(markerAttribute);
                    markerAttribute.nodeValue = "config";
                }
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="p.onload()">
        <div>
            <player id="Player1"></player>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could include Jquery and do the following:

```
$("#Player1").attr('config', 'write=all&settings;you,need');
```

Or something like:

```
$("#Player1").replaceWith('The html code u want');
```

Comment: So I would put that on pageload? Or does it have to be after the element has loaded?

Comment: You have to execute it after the html is loaded. You can do that by adding it on the bottom of your html or between an $(document).ready(function(){ /*you code here*/ }.